# How to count and get same items from list of tuples

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm writing a program that reads an excel file and creates a new one putting all the values in the right order and format, using openpyxl library.

I need to get some dates from the original file, where they are written in the same line, and create a new line for each one in the new file.

I already have a function to do that, but if 2 or more dates are equal they should be put in the same line, and I don't know how to do it :'(

Dates come with their IDs and are returned from another function like this:

```
      l = [(ID1, date1), (ID2, date2), (ID3, date3)]
```

This should be the final result:

```
if l == [(ID1, 20160101), (ID2, 20180101), (ID3, 20160101)]:
```

Line 1: 20160101 - ID1, ID3

Line 2: 20180101 - ID2

What's the best way to achive this?

This is what I've written so far (this creates a new row whether dates are equal or not):

```
def gestRid(fimport, fimpianto):

    for i in range(2, fimport.max_row + 1):

        if dateRid(fimpianto, i):

            for tupla in dateRid(fimpianto, i):

                cod, data = tupla

                ultima_riga = fimport.max_row + 1 ultima_riga == last_row

                for j in range(1, fimport.max_column + 1):

                    #Copies row at the end of worksheet
                    fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = j).value = fimport.cell(row = i, column = j).value 
                
                fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = 101).value = fimport.cell(row = i, column = 101).value + 1
                fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = 1).value = fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga - 1, column = 1).value + 1
                fimport.cell(row = i, column = 46).value = (datetime.strptime(str(data), '%Y%m%d').date() - timedelta(days = 1)).strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
                fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = 45).value = datetime.strptime(str(data), '%Y%m%d').strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
                fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = 48).value = fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = 45).value[6:]

                #Copies id in the first free cell
                if not fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = 78).value:
                    fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = 78).value = cod
                elif not fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = 82).value:
                    fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = 82).value = cod
                else:
                    fimport.cell(row = ultima_riga, column = 86).value = cod
```

Comment: I don't understand the format of your final result. What datastructure is this?

Comment: This should be the final result: Line 1: 20160101 - ID1, ID3

Line 2: 20180101 - ID2

Comment: The result has to be saved on an excel file, that's why I wrote it like that.

Answer (score 0):

One way to aggregate is using `collections.defaultdict(list)` and then print out the values from the `defaultdict` -

```py
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(list)
l = [("ID1", 20160101), ("ID2", 20180101), ("ID3", 20160101)]

for idx, dt in l:
    d[dt].append(idx)

for key, val in d.items():
    print(f'{key} - {", ".join(val)}')
```

**Output**

```
20160101 - ID1, ID3
20180101 - ID2
```

Comment: Ok but this prints only the IDs, how do I get the dates too? I have to write to excel the IDs with the corresponding date.

Comment: You need to make a change in your printing loop - loop over `items()` and print both the key and value - See edited answer.